# The difference between two values from different rows grouping by column

Tags: sql

Let's say there is a table jd_log:

```
job_name | duration
-------------------
A        | 10
B        | 2
B        | 3
C        | 15
A        | 12
D        | 100
C        | 9
```

What im trying to do, is to find the difference between 2 **duration**s (as **duration_diff**) for each unique **job_name**.
It is guaranteed, that for each unique **job_name** there will be no more than 2 entries in the table with such **job_name**. If there is only 1 entry for specific **job_name**, **duration_diff** should be null.

So the desired resultset should looks like following:

```
job_name | duration_diff
------------------------
A        | -2
B        | -1
C        | 6
D        | null
```

A: 10 - 12 = -2

B: 2 - 3 = -1

C: 15 - 9 = 6

D: null (as there is only 1 entry with such **job_name**)

The solution I came up with looks like this:

```
WITH unique_job_name AS (SELECT DISTINCT job_name FROM jd_log)
SELECT ujn.job_name, duration_diff
FROM unique_job_name ujn
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT job_name, (LAG(duration) OVER (PARTITION BY job_name) - duration) AS duration_diff
    FROM jd_log
  )
  WHERE duration_diff IS NOT NULL
) jndd
ON ujn.job_name = jndd.job_name
```

It seems to me that my solution looks overcomplicated and, perhaps, not entirely correct.

So I would like to know, if there is no simpler solution for such a problem?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question cannot be answered really unless there exist one or more columns which provides the *ordering* of the `duration` value.  Assuming say such an `id` column exist, your data might look like this:

```
id | job_name | duration
------------------------
1  | A        | 10
2  | B        | 2
3  | B        | 3
4  | C        | 15
5  | A        | 12
6  | D        | 100
7  | C        | 9
```

Then we could write a solution to your question using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY job_name ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    job_name,
    CASE WHEN MAX(rn) > 1 THEN
         SUM(CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN duration WHEN 2 THEN -duration END) END AS duration_diff
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    job_name;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. The only thing I think is that instead of "... THEN MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN duration END) - MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN duration END) ...", a better option would be "... THEN SUM(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN duration WHEN rn = 2 THEN -duration END) ..." according to Gordon Linoff's solution.

Comment: @zuffbq Thanks for the suggestion, and I agree with your comment.

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Your calculation requires an ordering.  If I assume there is an ordering column, then you can use window functions.  Here is one way:

```
select job_name,
       (case when count(*) = 2
             then sum(case when seqnum = 2 then duration
                           when seqnum = 1 then - duration
                      end)
        end) as diff
from (select l.*,
             row_number() over (partition by job_name order by <ordercol>) as seqnum
      from jd_log l
     ) l
group by job_name;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. The only thing is that this solution outputs incorrect duration_diff for job_names with only 1 entry in table, in such case duration_diff should be null.

Comment: @zuffbq . . . The code is easily modified to handle that situation.